# Packaging DSC configurations for TFS Release Management vNext

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I am trying to grasp Release Management vNext and dsc configuration 'management' (how to manage DSC configuration files). In the 'Deploy Using PS/DSC' dialog box while editing a vNext Release Template

Why is PSScriptPath relative?

Does it really mean, that I somehow have to get my scripts I want to use relative to my current drop folder? What is the best way to do achieve this? I want to be able to do:

- Have a separate git repository for configuration files
- Reuse configuration files across different projects

I've read a promising article [Packaging DSC configurations for Visual Studio / TFS Release Management vNext](http://writeabout.net/2015/03/22/packaging-dsc-configurations-for-visual-studio-tfs-release-management-vnext/) but it seems to be out dated and some kind of hack from my point of view.

How does Microsoft want us to use this? How to achieve reusable configurations in a separate repository?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a submodule to your separate configuration repository, then ensure the submodule is initialized during the build. You can then copy the configuration scripts to the build drop folder as part of your build script.

The reasoning is that your deployment scripts will evolve over time, and that evolution should be something that is captured. If you ever need to redeploy an old version of your software, that old version shouldn't be deployed using new scripts -- it should be deployed using the same version it used initially.